# Pass $(this) into a set timeout function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

Something like...

```
 $('.foo').live 'click', -> 
    setTimeout (()->$(this).parent().hide()), 5000
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this in setTimeout is going to be either `window` or undefined. In this case, you'd be better off either wrapping with an anonymous function to close over this, or using bind(this) to bind the this object for the function

```
setTimeout((function() { return function() { $(this).parent().hide(); } })(), 5000);
```

or

```
var func = function() { $(this).parent().hide(); };
setTimeout(func.bind(this), 5000);
```

(I don't know coffeescript very well, so hopefully this is the proper JS equivalent)

As a sidenote, doesn't jquery have a function to delay a animation like this?

Comment: thanks, and yes I could do `$(this).parent().delay(5000).hide(0)` needed a timeout here tho. thanks again

Comment: Instead of `func.bind(this)` (which isn't supported in all browsers), you can use CoffeeScript's fat arrow: `setTimeout (=> $(this).parent().hide()), 5000`. That takes care of binding the function to the current context, and it even works in IE6.

Answer (score 5):

James has correctly diagnosed the problem: When you pass a function to `setTimeout`, it's invoked in the `window` context (just as if you called `func` as `func()`). There are two good solutions:

1) **(Quickest)** Change the thin arrow `->` to the fat arrow `=>`, which binds the function to the current context, ensuring that `this` within the function has the same value as `this` outside of it. Then your code would be

```
$('.foo').live 'click', -> 
  setTimeout (=> $(this).parent().hide()), 5000
```

2) **(Most efficient)** Just capture the value of either `this` or `$(this)` outside of the function you're passing to `setTimeout`. This has less overhead than binding a function. Then your code would be

```
$('.foo').live 'click', -> 
  $this = $(this)
  setTimeout (-> $this.parent().hide()), 5000
```

I find myself writing `$this = $(this)` at the top of callbacks often. It's a very useful idiom that will save you a lot of headaches while ensuring smooth performance.

Answer (score 1):

CoffeeScript has the 'do' keyword which "immediately invokes the passed function". It should help here.

```
$('.foo').live 'click', -> 
  foo = $(this)
  do foo ->
    setTimeout (()->foo.parent().hide()), 5000
```

Comment: Actually, the `do foo ->` is superfluous in this case (as long as `foo`'s scope is the event handler). This is the most efficient approach. Write `$this = $(this)` at the top of the event handler and then use `$this` throughout.

Answer (score -1):

`$(this)` scoped to functions. Therefore `$(this)` here doesn't specify `$('.foo')` object. You first have to cache that object in some variable, and then pass that variable to your `setTimeout` function.

something like:

```
 var foo = $('.foo');
 setTimeout(foot.parent().hide(), 5000);
```